# Extended crank/no start

Tags: vw

I have a 2003 Jetta sedan 2.0 it has a 128,00 miles on and service has always been kept up on car. My problem is that after the car Is warm or in the heat which I live in the southwest so plenty of that. On extreme hot days or even after just running to gas station when I go to restart car it has a long extended crank may start but does so poor. Im to the point now if I drive it somewhere I dont shut off.Ive had it into Mechanics whom have done different things along with cleaning fuel injectors still problem exists.Ive even had a "master" volks wag tech whom was not able to figure out.. Fuel pump does not always prime when door opens but when turn the key I can here it prime. the passenger door actuator  needs to be replaced not sure if that has any effect. I know this is an old car but its in great shape and really cant afford a new one .. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Somewhere in the fuel system there is probably a fuel pressure accumulator, sounds like it is bleeding off when you turn it off, then the fuel pump has to run longer to fill it and attain required fuel pressure to start. Try this next time, key cycle it on then off 3 or 4 times where the fuel pump runs each time, then try to start.

Comment: If this should work when I try it what would be my next step as far a fixing can you advise... Thank you..

Comment: Replace the defective accumulator. It may or may not be part of the fuel pump. If your car has no accumulator, then replace the fuel pump.